# Highly coupled git submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project which needs to be split into two repositories: a set of common models, and a simulation based on those models, with additional code. Ultimately there may be multiple simulations using the same set of models, so having them in a separate repository is a definite requirement. The obvious solution is to have the common models as a submodule of the simulation.

Unfortunately, the two repositories will be *very* highly coupled. People will be very frequently adding something to their common models then immediately using it in the simulation. I imagine this will make for a lot of headaches in the integration process of the simulation's repo. In order to merge changes from many developers in the simulation, the integrator will have to do parallel merges in the common models submodule. On the other hand, it also makes it essential to use submodules - the simulation really *needs* to know which version of the common models it should be using.

The project is worked on by a sizeable number of people. Most of the developers have only a very cursory knowledge of git: they add files, commit, and pull from origin a lot, and hopefully have a dev and stable branch. The integrator has naturally learned quite a bit more, but anything involving submodules will certainly be new to him. Added bonus: I'm about to take a month of vacation, so I won't be able to put out any fires. The upshot is that there's a lot of incentive to make the workflow *really* hard to screw up, and to minimize the difference from people's previous workflows.

So, my questions are: am I going to regret recommending we use submodules for this? (Is there a better idea?) What kind of mistakes can I expect people to make, so I can warn against them in advance? Are there any good workflow strategies to keep in mind?

Edit: I just came across [git slave](http://gitslave.sourceforge.net/), which might be worth a look in this context too. Can't yet give a good evaluation of abilities/limitations beyond what's on its website.

Comment: Mmm.. may be I should wait for Jefromi to answer that one. He *really* knows a lot about Git ;)

Comment: @VonC: Haha, I know, it's weird being on the other side. But on the bright side, I finally have a student badge!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The submodule is a good choice for making sure to reference precise revision of the different component involved.
As I detailed in "[true nature of submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194)", you still can update any of the submodules, provided you commit them first (and then go to the parent repo and commit also)

However, for tightly coupled modules, I would try to avoid:

> "I imagine this will make for a lot of headaches in the integration process of the simulation's repo".

I don't see a central integration process working efficiently: it should only record new fast-forward evolutions.
For that to happens, any user wishing to push anything needs to pull first and rebase his changes on top of whatever new changes were already pushed there.
The developer is more apt to solve any conflict and/or ask his/her colleagues the origin of some modifications he/she has to deal with during the rebase.

This (pull, rebase, push) isn't always possible because of:

- "advanced" (less basic) Git operations involved (and a workflow not exactly identical to the current one)
- work involved (taking into account evolutions from other contributors)
- environment setting (it can be preferable to set up an extra environment were to make that rebase, which is again "not so basic"

But that would still be the direction I would try.

<sup>(... but maybe not *just before* a one month vacation ;)

Then again, who takes a *all* month of vacation?! Never heard of that concept before)</sup>

Comment: The one thing that makes central integration at least possible in our case is that developers have fairly isolated systems to work on, so merge conflicts are less common than they otherwise would be on a project this size. And unfortunately, developers don't push their work. The integrator pulls it. Everybody's stable branch, daily, with a script. Yes, all "topics" are merged every day. We call it "continuous integration."

Comment: And I will do my best to implant the suggestion of fast-forward-only updates. At the very least, I think we can get people to merge with origin, though rebase may be out of the question. Thanks for the link, as well. The detached HEAD thing is the one thing really scaring me at the moment, so I'm going to have to be pretty careful about my instructions for working within the submodules.

Comment: Well, I thought maybe I'd get one more answer, but oh well! Thanks for the advice. I'm going to take some extra precautions - hooks to strongly warn when committing with detached HEAD in the submodule, hooks to warn about needed submodule updates in the parent, etc etc. Congrats on the 100k rep, too!

Comment: @Jefromi: thanks for the congrats; I just discovered the hidden rights behind 100K rep! Namely, the right to go on for another 100K ;) Sorry for the lack of answers on this question though.

Comment: @VonC: "Then again, who takes a all month of vacation?!": Obviously you're not living in France :)

Comment: @Antoine: Err... I do actually. But as an administrator (both on the software and on the system side), I never take too much of holidays in one time (and I do remote connexion at work every day).

Answer (score 15):

A few notes for anyone else happening across this!

The biggest mistake rookies are going to make is committing with detached HEAD in the submodule, after having done a submodule update. I'm going to try to counter this with strong warnings from hooks.

The next biggest will probably be failing to do a submodule update after doing a checkout which requires one. Again, hooks can check for this and warn.

As for development process, this setup makes it much more important to have a good test infrastructure in the submodule, so that if possible you can work in it without having to do work in the parent, and avoid the issue entirely.

I'll try and post sample code from the hooks I end up using, and follow up after a month with (hopefully not too many) true horror stories.

Edit:

Here are the first drafts of the hooks. Keep in mind this is a rush job and go easy on me!

In the parent repo:

For post-merge and post-checkout, we warn the user if the submodule's out of sync. (post-merge is included in particular for fast-forward merges, pulling from origin) Also note that they'll want to check out a branch, though the submodule's post-checkout hook will also do that when they run submodule update. The more reminders the merrier.

```
#!/bin/bash
if git submodule status | grep '^+' > /dev/null; then
    echo "WARNING: common model submodule now out of sync. You probably want to run" 1>&2
    echo "         git submodule update, then make sure to check out an appropriate branch" 1>&2
    echo "         in the submodule." 1>&2
fi
```

For post-commit, if there are submodule changes, we warn the user that they may have forgotten to include them in their commit. In this highly coupled case, this is a very good guess. It's unlikely the user will have modified the simulation and common models *separately*.

```
#!/bin/bash
if git submodule status | grep '^+' > /dev/null; then
    echo "WARNING: common model submodule has changes. If the commit you just made depends" 1>&2
    echo "         on those changes, you must run git add on the submodule, and then run" 1>&2
    echo "         git commit --amend to fix your commit." 1>&2
fi
```

And in the submodule, a post-checkout hook to strongly warn about detached HEAD:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_ppid() {
    ps --no-headers -o ppid $1
}

# Check to see if this checkout is part of a submodule update
# git submodule calls git checkout, which calls this script, so we need to
# check the grandparent process.
if ps --no-headers -o command $(get_ppid $(get_ppid $$)) | grep 'submodule update' &> /dev/null; then
    if ! git symbolic-ref HEAD &> /dev/null; then
        echo "WARNING: common model submodule entering detached HEAD state. If you don't know" 1>&2
        echo "         what this means, and you just ran 'git submodule update', you probably" 1>&2
        echo "         want to check out an appropriate branch in the submodule repository." 1>&2
        echo
        # escape the asterisk from SO's syntax highlighting (it sees C comments)
        branches=($(git for-each-ref --format='%(objectname) %(refname:short)' refs/heads/\* | grep ^$(git rev-parse HEAD) | cut -d\  -f2))
        case ${#branches} in
            0 )
                ;;
            1 ) 
                echo "Branch '${branches[0]}' is at HEAD"
                ;;
            * )
                echo "The following branches are at HEAD: ${branches[@]}"
                ;;
        esac
    fi
    echo
fi
```

I'm also adding a pre-commit hook to simply abort commits made with detached HEAD (unless it's a rebase). I'm pretty terrified of getting the classic "all of my commits disappeared" panicked complaint. You can always bypass it with `--no-verify` if you know what you're doing.

Comment: @VonC: Thanks for the support, as always! I'll find out in a month if they decided to even try this without me - I expect I'll either have no news or some very scary lessons learned to post.

Comment: @Jefromi Many lessons learned over the last 2 years that you could share? I'm looking at adopting a very similar structure, but I am terrified of the developers who are terrified of git, and what they are going to do with a setup like this.

Comment: @Tyson I actually left that job not all that long after, so I don't have too much to share. My advice would probably be that if you have to try something like this, along with all the countermeasures to avoid things getting borked, make sure you have solid testing based off of the central repo so you can quickly catch and fix it when something inevitably gets borked.