# How do I organize my Git repo

Tags: git, layout, repository

I'm facing the following problem and don't have an answer to it:

We have a repo that was cloned from an SVN repo. The project stored in that repo is something like a platform software that gets used by various projects. The structure of the repo is like this:

```
platform
  |- core
  |- additional
```

The structure of that repo cannot be changed for some reasons. Both, `core` and `additional` contain data that are part of that `platform`.

If a project wants to use the platform and add some functionality, it creates a new folder under `additional` containing the sources and adds a header for that functionality to `additional/includes`

Currently, we simply branch off new projects from `master` and everything goes into the same repo. This leads to a branch inflation and my (central) repo grows more and more because all of the commits being made in the single projects go to the central repo (my colleagues are used to SVN, so they `push` nearly after each `commit` -- just to be sure...).

First I had in mind were [submodules](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html): keep `platform` as a submodule under a superproject (called `super`) and then go to `super/platform/additional/mystuff`, create the sources there and add them to `super`. But this obviously doesn't work because the files are inside the `platform` submodule.

Is there any better way to organize my repo, so that:

- users of the platform are able to update their working copy from the central repo
- **AND** users of the platform are able to apply bug fixes to the repo of `platform`
- **AND** the projects using `platform` don't mess up the repo of `platform`?

---

*EDIT 1*: [Highly coupled git submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712917/highly-coupled-git-submodules) covers quite a bit of the scenario I'm in: tightly coupled stuff, me the only one knowing a bit more than absolute basics of git, "Most of the developers have only a very cursory knowledge of git". Perfect match!

---

*EDIT 2*:
While the answer from [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680768/how-do-i-organize-my-git-repo-better-title-appreciated/6682970#6682970) looks promising, I think that it's a bit too complex to use. I'm looking for some really simple thing that doesn't need that much interaction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found your usage of `master` a bit confusing as I never knew
whether you meant the platform repository as a whole or just its
master branch.

My solution to this would be the following:

- You have one central repository for the *platform*.
- You have one central repository per *project*.
- Every *developer* has his/her own repository local.

### The central platform repository

This is where only the platform code goes to.  Use e.g. your
existing repo as a starting point here.

### The central project repository

This is a clone of the platform repository and keeps all the code
of a project. Init it with

```
$ git clone --bare /path/to/platform
```

### The developer's local repository

#### Init

You, as a developer, start by cloning the project repository.

```
$ git clone /path/to/project
```

#### Making changes to the project

Now, make your changes, commit them and push them to the projects
bare repo.

```
$ editor some-file
$ git add -p some-file
$ git commit
$ git push
```

Pull changes made by other developers to the projects bare repo
by using `git pull`.

#### Making changes to the platform

As you also want to make changes to the platform itself, you also
need a way to access the platform repo.  So you add it as a
remote repo to your local repo:

```
$ git remote add platform /path/to/platform
$ git fetch platform
```

As you can see now with `git branch -a`, your local repo knows
about the platform.  Now you want to make some changes to the
platform.  First you create a local branch *central* which is a
clone of the master branch of the platform repo:

```
$ git checkout -b central platform/master
```

You can always check which branch you're on by using `git branch`
or `git status`.  Now you make your changes and commit them (to
central, where your on).  As *central* is connected to
*platform/master* (checkout `cat .git/config`) you can push your
changes to the platform repo by simply using `git push`.  Also
`git pull` works without any other arguments.

Use `git checkout master` and `git checkout central` to change
between your branches.

#### Get a new platform version into your project

**Note:** *You need to have done the work from the previous section*.

First change to your platform branch and pull in the new version
of the platform:

```
$ git checkout central
$ git pull
```

Now go back to your project branch and merge the changes made in
the platform into your project branch.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge central
```

If a conflict occurs, something like this happens:

```
$ git merge central
Auto-merging index.html
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in index.html
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Open the files with the conflicts, resolve them, add them to the
staging area and commit the merge:

```
$ editor index.html
$ git add index.html
$ git commit
```

Now push your changes to the project's bare repo:

```
$ git push
```

More about merge conflicts: [Pro Git: Basic Merge Conflicts](http://progit.org/book/ch3-2.html)

If you do not want to change the platforms repo, but merge
changes from there into your project use

```
$ git remote add platform /path/to/platform
$ git fetch platform
$ git merge platform/master
```

The `git remote add` is only needed the first time you merge.
The other two are always required.

---

The part about merging is based on the [Pro Git Book](http://progit.org/book/) which is
licensed under cc-by-sa.  All other content of this post may be
considered public domain.

Comment: Updated my question to clean up usage of `master` (branch) and central (repo). Thanks for the hint.

Comment: +1 for providing a reasonable solution. But I'm afraid that I'll not be able to sell this workflow to my colleagues...

Comment: I know that it sounds very uncommon for svn users. But I think it isn't as complex at it sounds. You can provide a script to do the setup at the developer's side. Then she/he has only to handle two branches, i.e., `master` and `central`, and the merges between them. Also `git push` and `git pull` works in both branches without any arguments. I think that if you want to keep your central repo clean, you have to work with at least two branches.

Comment: The **central project repository** may also be a branch in the _central platform repository_. Just clone the central platform repo `git clone /path/to/platform`, create a new branch, e.g. _project-XYZ_, and push it to the central repo with `git push origin project-XYZ`. This keeps also your _master_ branch of _central_ clean, but is imho a bit less flexible.