# How to checkout a branch with submodule from a branch without it

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have three branches on my local machine:

- master
- feature-branch-with-submodule
- feature-branch-without-submodule

The branch without submodule used to have a submodule, and I removed the submodule by following instructions from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1260982/10906478). I did not want to remove submodule from `master` and `feature-branch-with-submodule`.

However, now that I am done with `feature-branch-without-submodule`, I want to switch to `feature-branch-with-submodule`. So I do **git checkout**, but got the error:

```
fatal: not a git repository: src/vendor/mysubmodule/../../../../../.git/modules/src/vendor/mysubmodule
```

How do I fix it so that the branch with submodule has it, and the branch without does not, and that I can freely switch back and forth using git checkout?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is git submodule update not automatic on git checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899792/why-is-git-submodule-update-not-automatic-on-git-checkout)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+switch+branches

Comment: If `git checkout --recurse-submodules` is not enough you should consider using `post-checkout` hook like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3721388/7976758).

Answer (score 6):

For 1-2 days I've been wondering what's the problem.
Here is a link with the most approximate (and really awful) answer I've found so far:

[Checkout branch with different submodules is not working](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/3065)

And for a quick answer:

```
Supposing, for example, branch master has submodule A and branch alpha has submodule B.

To properly checkout master you should, essentially
git submodule deinit .
git checkout master
git submodule update --init --recursive

To go back to alpha, again
git submodule deinit .
git checkout alpha
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Comment: I had a very similar problem: need to switch between a branch with a submodule, and a branch without. Your answer put me on the right track.
I'll propose you some clarification edit when I'm able to (something with a full "suggested edit queue" on SO, Don't really know what it is).

Answer (score 0):

#### feature-without-submodule to feature-with-submodule

If you've completed removed the submodule (i.e. even the cache in `.git/modules/path/to/submodule`), then here's one way that seems to work.

(I assume you're working with a clean working tree. That is, no modified files to begin with.)

```sh
rm -rf <path> # Optional: if you have files in the path.
git submodule add [--name <name>] <repository> <path>
git submodule deinit -f <path>
git checkout -f feature-branch-with-submodule
```

0. Delete existing files in the submodule path.
1. Reintroduce the deleted submodule. The objective is to initialise the `.git/modules/<name>` folder to the repository so that `git merge` is happy. You'll need:

   - the repository of the submodule
   - the path to the submodule
   - the name passed to `--name` (not needed if same as path)

   You can find these by looking at your diffs of `.gitmodules`.
2. De-initialise the submodule.
3. Forcefully checkout!

#### feature-with-submodule to feature-without-submodule

To return to the original state, checkout to feature-branch-without-submodule, then run the following to remove cached files:

```sh
rm -rf .git/modules/<name>
```

This is so that in the future you can `git submodule add` a submodule with the same name.

Additionally, if you want the submodule folder to be removed entirely, run:

```sh
rm -rf <path>
```

(Not needed if files already exist in submodule folder.)